# No CSS after upgrading to 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2.4.5, php8, magento2.4.5p1

I upgraded from 2.4.4-p2 to 2.4.5-p1 and now the frontend and backend have no CSS and images.

With the upgrade I also changed from PHP 7.4 to 8.1.

Any idea what the problem causes?

Comment: If possible can you share the screenshot for this?

Comment: The problem is already solved. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by upgrading to composer v2.